# having a flutter srollable drawer but the issue is when i try to wrap the text inside expanded or flexible the drawer will not build

Tags: flutter, dart

----------------------IGNORE THE FIRST PARARAGH--------------------------------------

i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web.i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web.i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web.i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web.i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web.

i am using a drawer with custom design. the issue is when i try to wrap text or circleAvatar  with flexible/expanded widget the drawer will not build. i want my text or circle avatar to adjust according to the screen size as i resize my screen using web. i also used LayOut builder but it was also of no use.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BistroCustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  BistroCustomDrawer({
    super.key,
  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        child:Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap:(){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Color(0xffF1C452),)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all( 8.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xffF1C452),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 56,
                            child: Image(

                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/userImage.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [

                            Expanded(
                              child: Text("Zee Lounge",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                    fontSize: 28
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(" 0300 000 0000",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                    fontSize: 16
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                FittedBox(
                                  fit:BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text("4.5(5 Reviews)",
                                  style:TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                      fontSize: 16
                                  ),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: Color(0xff212129),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Profile Details",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("What inspired me to become a host?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Culnary journey",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),



                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Interests",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),





                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("Social Media Handles",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),






              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

the issue i am encounter in code snippet is:

```
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [

                            Expanded(
                              child: Text("Zee Lounge",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                    fontSize: 28
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(" 0300 000 0000",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                    fontSize: 16
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                FittedBox(
                                  fit:BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text("4.5(5 Reviews)",
                                  style:TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                      fontSize: 16
                                  ),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code block just wrap the padding with Expanded widget and  and inside the row widget where reviews child text widget is used here also wrap with Expanded widget.
However, this makes your circular image as larger so you need to play with expanded widget by wrapping both children widgets inside row and passing flex. Below code will just remove your error.

Here is [dartpad code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=32232095f84f4da867728fb876e74e59) it working good in web, no issue but on mobile screen circular image will get larger

[image]

```
    class BistroCustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  BistroCustomDrawer({
    super.key,
  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        child:Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap:(){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Color(0xffF1C452),)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all( 8.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF1C452),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 56,
                            child: Image.network(
                                'https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/dash/dash-fainting.gif'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 8,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              Text("Zee Lounge",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                    fontSize: 28
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                              Text(" 0300 000 0000",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                    fontSize: 16
                                ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  FittedBox(
                                    fit:BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text("4.5(5 Reviews)",
                                      style:TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xff8EA659),
                                          fontSize: 16
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: const Color(0xff212129),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 6),
                  child: const Text("Profile Details",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("What inspired me to become a host?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Culnary journey",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Interests",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("Social Media Handles",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: const Color(0xff212129),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 6),
                  child: const Text("Profile Details",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("What inspired me to become a host?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Culnary journey",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("My Interests",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 6, bottom: 0),
                  child: Text("Social Media Handles",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffFEE4A4),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top: 0, bottom: 6),
                  child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff909094),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```